# Closing a WPF within Thread - C#

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, dialog

I have a thread that shows a dialog. The reason I use a thread for this is because I want the dialog to show immediately (so I use `ShowDialog()`)) while the main thread continue do some heavy work. When the main thread finish with the "heavy" function, I want the dialog to stop showing.

This is the code i'm using:

```
Thread searchingAlertThread = (new Thread(() =>
{
    SearchingAlert searchingAlert = new SearchingAlert();
    try {
        searchingAlert.ShowDialog();
    } catch (ThreadAbortException) { // Thrown when the thread is aborted
        searchingAlert.Close();
    }                        
}));
searchingAlertThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);

searchingAlertThread.Start(); // Starts the thread
BluetoothDeviceInfo[] devices = client.DiscoverDevices(); // Takes 15 seconds
searchingAlertThread.Abort(); // Stops the thread
```

The `searchingAlert` is **WPF window** dialog that shows `TextView` and `ImageView` with animated gif.

The problem is, that sometimes when this called is called more then once (in case it didn't find any devices), the `ImageView` is not shown, and more important, the `ThreadAbortException` isn't thrown.
Is that a proper way of closing a thread with a dialog?

Comment: Use `Invoke()` to `Close()` the dialog.

Comment: @SLaks sorry for the misunderstanding but it's WPF... I've edited the question

Comment: Dont use ShowDialog. If you need to open a thread just to create one window over the other, it means that something is wrong... why not open a window or create a usercontrol which displays progress instead?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are at least two major problems with the original example: running a new UI thread and aborting a thread. Try this instead:

```
SearchingAlert searchingAlert = new SearchingAlert();
BluetoothDeviceInfo[] devices = null;

searchingAlert.Loaded += async (sender, e) =>
{
    devices = await Task.Run(() => client.DiscoverDevices());
    searchingAlert.Close();
};

searchingAlert.ShowDialog();

// Use the devices array here
```

It's not clear what `client` is, but of course if it offers an async version of the `DiscoverDevices()` method, you should just await on that instead of using `Task.Run()`.

Comment: Thank you SharonKo for trying to fix the code in my answer. I'm surprised your edit was rejected by the other SO reviewers. It was a good edit, and I've gone ahead and instated the changes you proposed.